# Is there any performance issue if we add 95 fields in one collection in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie in mongodb. I have a collection it's name is `user`. At-present this collection has 95 fields. Is it affect the performance to store 95 fields in one collection or Do I need to split as two collections?

Comment: You already have it, you should be able to test pretty easily whether it affects anything and specifically *whether it's fast enough for you.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that each document in the collection has 95 fields.
It all depends about how you are going to use your data knowing that MongoDB is not designed to join collections (like an SQL join) on the server side.

My guess is that storing you 95-fields-documents in a collection and using indexes according to the type of queries you need will gives the best performances.
I would suggest you read a bit of documentation about:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query